# Python Pandas: How to append a dataframe to another whilst iterating?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I am searching a config dump in an excel format.

I am looking for IP address matches for in which I can collect a new dataframe or list of the rows that match.

So far, I have managed to iterate both columns of IP addresses and when they match look up the row and assign to a variable.

Now I am stuck as the variable one amended using the pandas dataframe amend method doesn't seem to work.

I then tried appending to a regular list only this time I know get more information than I need:

68    0
Name: Next reference index, dtype: int64

I'd love some help trying to figure out how to either get rid of the extra data and only keep the values, or in creating a new dataframe with all the matches for further processing.

```
# iterate through the two lists of ips and look for 
# duplicate values, if value is nan then skip
for line_1 in df_1['IPv4 address']:
    # ignore null lines
    if 'nan' in str(line_1):
        pass
        for line_2 in df_2['IPv4 address']:
            if 'nan' in str(line_2):
                pass
            # if the ip addresses match
            if line_1 == line_2:
                # look up the row in the dataframes ready for comparison
                result_1 = df_1.loc[df_1['IPv4 address'] == line_1]
                result_2 = df_2.loc[df_2['IPv4 address'] == line_2]

                # should I append the different details to a list?
                # or append to a dataframe? 
                # when appending to a dataframe it did not seem to work
                # and returned an empty dataframe
                result = (str(result_1['IP route name'])
                          + str(result_1['IPv4 address'])
                          + str(result_1['Next reference index']))
                results.append(result)
```

I expect the output to be either a new dataframe with all the matches or a list with each line being the 3 values

```
# Example df
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLPMv.png)

Comment: Hi, Can you give an example of df_1 and df_2 please ?

Comment: Can you see the image I've attached above? Small extract.

Comment: ok, you have created df_1 and df_2 by splitting df ?

Comment: No the image is an example of the data and its headers, the excel spreadsheet has two sheets within it. So df_1 is sheet 1 and df_2 is sheet 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this : 
You join the two dataframes after renaming the columns, and then you compare directly the columns IPV4 by doing a pandas filter, with this you extract only the lines you want :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["ip_route1", "1.1.1.1",1], ["ip_route2", "2.2.2.2",2],["ip_route2", "4.3.3.4",3]]),columns=['IP_ROUTE', 'IPV4_AD','REF_INDEX'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["ip_route1", "1.1.1.1",1], ["ip_route2", "2.2.2.2",2], ["ip_route2", "3.3.3.3",3]]),columns=['IP_ROUTE', 'IPV4_AD','REF_INDEX'])

print(df1)
#     IP_ROUTE  IPV4_AD REF_INDEX
# 0  ip_route1  1.1.1.1         1
# 1  ip_route2  2.2.2.2         2
# 2  ip_route2  3.3.3.3         3

print(df2)
#     IP_ROUTE  IPV4_AD REF_INDEX
# 0  ip_route1  1.1.1.1         1
# 1  ip_route2  2.2.2.2         2
# 2  ip_route2  4.3.3.4         3

df1 = df1.rename(columns={"IPV4_AD": "IPV4_AD1", "IP_ROUTE":"IP_ROUTE_1"}).set_index("REF_INDEX")
df2 = df2.rename(columns={"IPV4_AD": "IPV4_AD2", "IP_ROUTE":"IP_ROUTE_2"}).set_index("REF_INDEX")

df = df1.join(df2).reset_index()

print(df)
#   REF_INDEX IP_ROUTE_1 IPV4_AD1 IP_ROUTE_2 IPV4_AD2
# 0         1  ip_route1  1.1.1.1  ip_route1  1.1.1.1
# 1         2  ip_route2  2.2.2.2  ip_route2  2.2.2.2
# 2         3  ip_route2  3.3.3.3  ip_route2  4.3.3.4

TempResult = df[df["IPV4_AD1"]==df["IPV4_AD2"]]
print(TempResult)
#   REF_INDEX IP_ROUTE_1 IPV4_AD1 IP_ROUTE_2 IPV4_AD2
# 0         1  ip_route1  1.1.1.1  ip_route1  1.1.1.1
# 1         2  ip_route2  2.2.2.2  ip_route2  2.2.2.2

result = TempResult[["IP_ROUTE_1","IPV4_AD1"]]
# .rename(columns={"IP_ROUTE_1","IP_ROUTE","IPV4_AD1","IPV4_AD"})
print(result)$
#   IP_ROUTE_1 IPV4_AD1
# 0  ip_route1  1.1.1.1
# 1  ip_route2  2.2.2.2
```

Comment: Is it ok for you @Henry James ?

Comment: No sorry this doesn't answer my question I'm affraid!